# Why perl debugger shows Term::ReadLine::Stub::new when new Term::ReadLine is called?

Tags: perl

```
Term::ReadLine::Stub::new(/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/Term/ReadLine.pm:243):
```

I was expecting to see `Term::ReadLine::new`, which is generally the case when I `new` a package.

Anyone knows the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's inheritance.  Term::Readline starts out with `package Term::ReadLine::Stub` at the top, and then later within `package Term::ReadLine` you will see the following:

```
our @ISA;
if (defined &Term::ReadLine::Gnu::readline) {
  @ISA = qw(Term::ReadLine::Gnu Term::ReadLine::Stub);
} elsif (defined &Term::ReadLine::Perl::readline) {
  @ISA = qw(Term::ReadLine::Perl Term::ReadLine::Stub);
} elsif (defined $which && defined &{"Term::ReadLine::$which\::readline"}) {
  @ISA = "Term::ReadLine::$which";
} else {
  @ISA = qw(Term::ReadLine::Stub);
}
```

sub `new()` is created within Term::ReadLine::Stub and inherited into Term::ReadLine.

The debugger is most helpful if it actually tells you where a sub is being inherited from (as it does).  It would not be so helpful if you were directed by the debugger to Term::ReadLine, and then you had to wade through all the @ISA levels until you found one that defined new().  Imagine that quagmire in an object system that allows for multi-tier inheritance (as Perl does), and multiple inheritance (as Perl does).